# Log4Net with .NetCore Dependency Injection cannot output method name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net

I'm try to use log4net in my ASP.Net Core app.

When I use classic way to get ILog :

```
private readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Everything work fine

but when I use .NetCore ILogger with Dependency Injection

```
    public Worker2(ILogger<Worker2> logger, ILifetimeScope scope)
    {
        this._log = logger;
        this.LifetimeScope = scope;
    }
```

The output method name always show "LogMessage"

[My Program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyfQ0.png)

My logger setting is like this

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureLogging(logger =>
            {
                logger.ClearProviders();
                logger.AddLog4Net("log4net.config", true);
            })
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<TestOBJ1>().InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope("Status");
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                services.AddHostedService<Worker2>();
            });
```

My log4net Config file is here

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss} [%method] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

Is there any way to let ILogger output currect Method Name?

Update:
BTW, here is my Nuget package

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.1.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.8" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: As an alternative, you could add an extension-method to `ILog` that uses `CallerMemberNameAttribute`.

Comment: Have you considered using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` as a frontend for Log4Net?

Comment: @Dai  As far as I know, I'm doing the same thing.   
There is my Nuget package reference.